# Hiding my program in the System Tray in Windows

Tags: java, windows, swing, system-tray

I'd like my program to display an icon in the TaskBar Status Area near the clock in Windows and found a way to do so.

The thing is, I'd like my program to stay open in the Status Area if the "X" is pressed on the window, but not in the System Tray, but I have no idea how to do so and searching on Google didn't help (I'm probably not searching the right terms).

**Edit:** I think I used the wrong terms. I know how to have my program's icon in the notification area, what I'd like is to hide it in the area where it is normally displayed when you minimize a window.

Comment: The official name for the _system tray_ is the _notification area_ (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/10/54831.aspx)). That might aid your search.

Comment: @user786653 Funnily even if the Java implementation goes under the name system tray. That's one fight raymond and co have just lost - together with their official guide how to use it (which is imo a good thing~)

Comment: Voo: The Java implementation works on more systems than just Windows and other window managers adopted the term »system tray« ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I know how to have my program's icon in the notification area, what I'd like is to hide it in the area where it is normally displayed when you minimize a window.

Then don't use the system tray.

> The thing is, I'd like my program to stay open in the Status Area if the "X" is pressed on the window,

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't looking at the correct methods. I guess I should have figured that by making it not visible it would hide it.

Answer (score 6):

System Tray support was added in JavaSE v 6.

you can see example here 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SystemTray.html

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class HideToSystemTray extends JFrame {
    TrayIcon trayIcon;
    SystemTray tray;
    JButton button;

    HideToSystemTray() {
        super("SystemTray test");
        button = new JButton("Press");
        button.setBounds(10, 10, 40, 40);
        setUndecorated(true);
        getContentPane().add(button);
        System.out.println("creating instance");
        try {
            System.out.println("setting look and feel");
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to set LookAndFeel");
        }
        if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            System.out.println("system tray supported");
            tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

            Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\Sandipan\\Desktop\\cutter.png");
            ActionListener exitListener = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Exiting....");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            };
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
            MenuItem defaultItem = new MenuItem("Exit");
            defaultItem.addActionListener(exitListener);
            popup.add(defaultItem);
            defaultItem = new MenuItem("Open");
            defaultItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    tray.remove(trayIcon);
                    setVisible(true);
                    System.out.println("Tray icon removed");
                }
            });
            popup.add(defaultItem);
            trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "SystemTray Demo", popup);
            trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
        } else {
            System.out.println("system tray not supported");
        }

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //Execute when button is pressed
                System.out.println("You clicked the button");
                try {
                    tray.add(trayIcon);
                    setVisible(false);
                    System.out.println("added to SystemTray");
                } catch (AWTException ex) {
                    System.out.println("unable to add to tray");
                }
            }
        });


    /*  addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() { 
    public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) { 
        if(e.getNewState()==ICONIFIED){ 
            try { 
                tray.add(trayIcon); 
                setVisible(false); 
                System.out.println("added to SystemTray"); 
            } catch (AWTException ex) { 
                System.out.println("unable to add to tray"); 
            } 
        } 
        if(e.getNewState()==7){ 
            try{ 
                tray.add(trayIcon); 
                setVisible(false); 
                System.out.println("added to SystemTray"); 
            }catch(AWTException ex){ 
                System.out.println("unable to add to system tray"); 
            } 
        } 
        if(e.getNewState()==MAXIMIZED_BOTH){ 
            tray.remove(trayIcon); 
            setVisible(true); 
            System.out.println("Tray icon removed"); 
        } 
        if(e.getNewState()==NORMAL){ 
            tray.remove(trayIcon); 
            setVisible(true); 
            System.out.println("Tray icon removed"); 
        } 
    } 
    }); */
    setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\Sandipan\\Desktop\\cutter.png"));

    setVisible(true);
    setSize(300, 200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new HideToSystemTray();
}
}
```

Comment: Please add some details about the code, and why you commented out a big part of it so that it's easier for other people to understand it

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want the taskbar button to be removed when you minimise the main form. You achieve this by petting its visible property to false, however you do that with your Java framework.